# Invoking Java Applet with dynamic parameters

Tags: java, html, applet

Here's the scenario. The user fill a form with a certain number of parameters in an html page, then I need to invoke my applet with this specific parameters, possibly within the same page. What's the easiest way to perform this pass?

I'm using the runApplet function, but it's not working. No messages in the JS console and in the Java console.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Compila i dati</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src=
  "http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
    function runApplet(){
        var attributes = { id:'anID', code:'Test',  width:1, height:1, codebase: '.'} ;
        var parameters = {width:'100', height:'100', code:'Test', archive: 'applet.jar, xyz.jar, abc.jar', 
        posX: document.forms["form1"]["posX"].value , posY: document.forms["form1"]["posY"].value , heightSign: '300' , widthSign: '600' , 
        PDFUrl: 'http://anurl' , 
        type:'application/x-java-applet' , scriptable:'false' } ;
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, 1.6);
    }
</script>


<form name = "form1" onsubmit="runApplet()">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="mail">Cognome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="cognome" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="msg">X:</label>
        <input type="text" name="posX" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="msg">Y:</label>
        <input type="text" name="posY" />
    </div>

    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Invia</button>
    </div>
</form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I could try to create an dinamic applet contanier via javascript in this way:

```
 $('#idappletv').empty();
       $('#idappletv').hide();
        var _xmhlcode = "  <script>  function javafxEmbed() {" +
        "dtjava.embed( " +
        "{" +
        "    id: 'myBrApplet'," +
        "    url : 'pages/applet/myApplet.jnlp'," +
        "    placeholder : 'javafx-app-placeholder'," +
        "    width : 890   ," +
        "    height : 200," +
        "    jnlp_content : 'bmFtZT0iQXBwbGV0RnhCcm93c2VyIiAvPg0KICA8dXBkYXRlIGNoZWNrPSJhbHdheXMiLz4NCjwvam5scD4NC=='" +
        ", params: {param1:'" + param1 + "',param2:'" + param2 + "'}" +
        "}," +
        "{" +
        "    javafx : '2.2+'" +
        "}," +
        "{}" +
        ");" +
        "}" +
        "dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbed); </" + "script> ";

        $('#idappletv').append("<div id='javafx-app-placeholder'></div>");
        $('#idappletv').append(_xmhlcode);
        dtjava.addOnloadCallback(javafxEmbed);
        $('#idappletv').show();
```

Then when the applet starts you can read the parameter using:

```
 @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Parameters params = getParameters();
        String param1 = params.getNamed().get("param1");
        String param2 = params.getNamed().get("param2");
```

You can read the parameter "param1 and param2" from your html page.

It should be works.
I used JavaFX with java-webstart (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_swing_apps.htm).